# Hangman game - while loop with condition "contained in an array"

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm creating a hangman game. I'm having a problem asking the user to reenter a new guess(char) if they have entered that same one already(these are contained in the letters[] array). I have started with a while loop that asks the user to reenter if "guess" matches one of the chars that stored in the array. Thanks.

```
void play(string word)
{
    string copy = word;

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        copy[i] = ' ';
    }

    bool match = false;
    bool valid = false;
    int chance = 5;
    char letters[26];
    int counter = 0;
    char guess;
    while (chance > 0 && match == false)
    {
        int blanks = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            if(copy[i] == ' ')
                blanks++;
        }

        cout << '|';
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            cout << copy[i] << '|';
        }
        cout << "\t(There are '" << blanks << "' blanks)" << endl;
        cout << "Incorrect letters guessed: ";

        for (int i = 0; i<counter; i++)
        {
            cout << "'" << letters[i] << "' ";
        }

        cout << "\n\nEnter guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            if(guess == letters[i])
                valid = true;
        }

        while (valid == true)
        {

            for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                if(guess == letters[i])
                    valid = true;
                else
                    valid = false;
            }
            if (valid)
            {
                cout << "\n\nAlready tried that one. Enter guess: ";
                cin >> guess;
            }

        }
        long find = word.find(guess);

        if (find != string::npos)
        {
            copy[find] = word[find];
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            {
                if (word[i] == word[find])
                {
                    copy[i] = word[find];
                }
            }
        }



        else
        {
            chance--;

            letters[counter] = guess;
            counter++;
            printMan(chance);
        }



        if (copy == word)
        {
            match = true;
        }
    }

    if (match == true)
        cout << "\nYou saved a life! You managed to win! Congrats, cheater." << endl;
    else
        cout << "\nThe man has been hung! You LOSE! The word was '" << word << "', you idiot." << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            if(guess == letters[i])
                valid = true;
            else
                valid = false;
        }
```

The problem with this for loop is that after you find a valid guess... you don't stop looping.

You go on and check if letter equals the next value in the loop too - and the next and the next. and `valid` keeps getting overwritten over and over until you get to the end of the loop - at which time `valid` equals the value of the check against the *last* letter in `letters`.

so your "check guess" code only gets called if `guess` matches the last letter in `letters`.

You need to look up how to exit out of a loop at the moment that you find a matching guess.